# Differentials on curve, Fulton Ex. 8.23

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve, $P\in X$, $f\in k(X)$. I am currently trying to show that if $f\in\mathcal{O}_{P}$ then $\frac{df}{dt}\in\mathcal{O}_{P}$ using the method of Ex. 8.23 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves.

So far I have considered the map $\varphi:\mathcal{O}_{P}\rightarrow k[[T]],\ t\mapsto T$ where $t$ is a uniformising parameter at $P$, so far I have shown that if we consider the power series expansion of $f=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}t^{i}$ then applying the usual derivation gives $df=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ia_{i}t^{i-1})dt$, hence the image of $\frac{df}{dt}$ in $k[[T]]$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ia_{i}T^{i-1}$, which is the formal derivative of $\varphi(f)$. I'm just not sure how this shows that $\frac{df}{dt}\in\mathcal{O}_{P}$.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that $\varphi$ is an injective homomorphism?